# List View Item Binding

Tags: c#, android, .net, mono, xamarin

I got a scenario where i need to bind ListView in android xamarin with audio file name.
which should display only first 5 character of audio name. i did this by splitting it and it is working fine.

```
adapter = new ArrayAdapter<string> ( this , Resource.Layout.list_item ,       Resource.Id.audio_names , lstSearchResult.ToArray () );
listResult.Adapter = adapter;
```

in the above code lstSearchResult contains audio name with 5 character.

Problem is : onItemClick i need to get full audio name, to be played later. how can i do that?

```
listResult.ItemClick += delegate(object sender , AdapterView.ItemClickEventArgs e )
        {
            string strItem= adapter.GetItem(e.Position);  
        };
```

any suggestion/alternate vl be appreciated

Comment: set the the DataContext of the sender to an instance of your object and the get the full data from there

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best thing to do is to create custom adapter.
First of all create your own layout for one row. Call it "SongListRow" (or any other name).

Then create a class for your songs:

```
public class Song {
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string File { get; set; }
}
```

Then create the adapter:

```
public class SongListAdapter : BaseAdapter<Song> {
    private List<Song> _items;
    private Activity _context;

    public SongListAdapter(Activity context, List<Song> songs)
    {
        this._items = songs;
        this._context = context;
    }

    public override Song this[int position]
    {
        get { return this._items[position]; }
    }

    public override int Count
    {
        get { return this._items.Count; }
    }

    public override long GetItemId(int position)
    {
        return position;
    }

    public override View GetView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
    {
        var item = this._items[position];
        View view = convertView;
        //If there is nothing to reuse, then create view from your row layout
        if (view == null)
            view = this._context.LayoutInflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.SongListRow, null); 

        view.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.SongTitle).Text = item.Name; 

        return view;
    }
}
```

Now, in your activity, declare a variable for your adapter

```
private SongListAdapter _songsAdapter;
```

Now create a generic list of your songs, create the adapter and pass the song list to the adapter's constructor. Then you can do something like this:

```
listResult.Adapter = this._songsAdapter;
listResult.ItemClick += (s,e) => {
    var fileName = this._songsAdapter[e.Position].File;
    // Play your song
}
```

Comment: If an item is added, removed, etc, or simply changed in the list<Song> the listResult (UI) does not get updated. How to deal with this?